# Django ORM: child's fields & values not inherited. Objects duplicated. (Using Django admin interface)

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I'm trying to have a variety of dishes (Pizza, Subs, etc) that inherit from a common (concrete) parent
 `class Dish`. (Logically, I have no reason for it to be concrete other than having had difficulties 
implementing it).

Every pizza (or other concrete dish) corresponds to exactly one dish ID (implemented as FK here) and every 
dish (ID) is exactly one pizza.

I am new to this, but based on my understanding, the shared fields (name, type price, size and dish ID (PK
for `Dish` = FK `dish_id` for `Pizza`)) in `Dish` as well as their values
 are inherited by children such as `Pizza`. So much for the theory.

Now I implemented the classes as per below. And then I use the Django Admin interface to create objects, but 
against expectations, when I create a `Dish` object of type 'Pizza', automatically a `Pizza` object is 
created. Now when I go into that `Pizza` object, the name, type, price and size fields are blank. 
Shouldn't they be aready set when I select `Pizza`'s `dish` attribute as the `Dish`-object
I just created?

And also when I start by creating a `Pizza`, selecting the corresponding parent (or creating it in
the Django admin interface), I need to populate all the common fields twice (once in `Dish` and then again in `Pizza`).

And whichever way I do it, I end up with duplicate entries: 1 pizza for the `Pizza` object I created
and 1 pizza for the Dish type I created for that pizza. (same vice versa, 1 dish for the dish created and
1 dish for the pizza I created).

What is my mistake and is it a design flaw or is it the way I create the database entries?

```
class Dish(models.Model):
  PIZZA = 'PIZZA'
  SUB = 'SUB'
  PASTASALAD = 'PASTASALAD'
  PLATTER = 'PLATTER'
  TYPE_CHOICES = ( (PIZZA, 'Pizza'), (SUB, 'Sub'), (PASTASALAD, 'PastaSalad'), (PLATTER, 'Platter') )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True) # blank makes name optional
  type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True)
  size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SIZE_CHOICES, default=SMALL, blank=True)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=None)

class Pizza(Dish):
  dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_id_pizza")
  REGULAR = 'REGULAR'
  SICILIAN = 'SICILIAN'
  STYLE_CHOICES = ( (REGULAR, 'Regular'), (SICILIAN, 'Sicilian'),)
  style = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default=REGULAR)
  topping_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of OneToOne relationship, since you want exactly one.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    dish = models.OneToOneField(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_id_pizza")
```

This should solve the duplicate issue and prepopulating itself and blank fields.

Note: that you should also write the str dunder methods to easily track each model field. like this.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: Thank you - that almost sorts me out, I think. I noticed though that in your example Pizza isn't inheriting from Dish - is that intentional? (I did write the str - just left it out here, but thanks for the hint!! :) )

Comment: I just changed it to ```dish = models.OneToOneField(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_id_pizza", parent_link=True)```, but now I don't see any link to in the Django admin interface at all. The ```dish``` field has entirely disappeared from ```Pizza```, so I can't tell Django which parent to link to and hence again am prompted to populate size, price, etc.

Comment: I want to have a ```Dish``` where attributes (fields) price, name, type and size are inherited (shared, i.e. the same) as the ones for the corresponding child ```Pizza``` object. So if my dish object with ID #17 is type=Pizza, price=20, size=L, name=Cheese - logically its child pizza object should have all those exact same characteristics, but instead they are blank, I not only can, but HAVE to override them. Shouldn't the ```Dish``` and ```Pizza``` objects be linked by the OneToOne ID of 17?

Comment: @Anna I found out something while working on your code. Try filling the fields in the child table you will notice the parent table Dish is automatically filled and linked to the child table Pizza. You also make the parent class abstract as well.

Comment: That is my problem with making Dish abstract. I run into a bunch of errors as soon as I include ```class Meta:
        abstract = True```. Namely: ```orders.Pizza.dish: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'orders.Dish', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
orders.Pizza.dish: (fields.E307) The field orders.Pizza.dish was declared with a lazy reference to 'orders.dish', but app 'orders' doesn't provide model 'dish'.``` As suggested by other posts, I tried including the app name in: ```dish = models.OneToOneField('orders.Dish', ..``` but that doesn't work either :(

Comment: @Anna it's best you only inherit your created models if you have multiple models that shares similar fields, else just stick to onetoone or onetomany relationships. Inheritance in models is similar to inheritance in OOP, it doesn't mean what you wrote inside the parent table field must reflect. Instead the child table will reflect on the parent table field with an object number.